# Using the space bar as a shortcut in finder to preview audio files

Tags: keyboard, finder, macos

I recently was given an old MacBook (Late 2007) running 10.4 from a family member. I'm using it basically as a backup for my studio computer. It's going to contain only the apps included in 10.7 and 1 additional NI audio product. My question is, my other mac and all I've ever worked on (and it's a few) have been able to use the space bar to preview a highlighted audio file in Finder. Is there a way to cut this off/on? I really like this feature and it saves me probably 30-60 minutes a day because I go through thousands of audio files a day.

Comment: Are you using 10.4 or 10.7? The question is somewhat unclear here.

Comment: sorry I see what you mean, it's running 10.4 now waiting on tiger to arrive at the moment.

Comment: Lion, I guess you mean... Tiger is 10.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Quick View is only available for Mac OS X 10.5 and later.

Bottom line, download [10.5](http://mac-os-x-10-5-6.en.softonic.com/mac) and the spacebar Quick Look will work.

As a side note, if you're looking for other shortcuts that might be missing from OS 10.4, there's a shortcut creator (on steroids) that's free, and it's called BetterTouchTool. Go here to download it (http://www.bettertouchtool.net). Just remember you have to have 10.8 or later for it work.

You won't regret it.

Comment: Thanks I was afraid it was a 10.4 thing..... upgrading soon tho!!!!

Comment: installed snow leppard today and I'll be *#$@$# there it is!!!!!! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome :). Vote the answer up so the community benefits!

Comment: I have but need to get my rep up to get there....so help me out

Comment: @ScottPuig lmao. Ah, I see. :).